# Why does realloc not update the size of my array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc, realloc

I am trying to read in user input then parse it to tokens using strtok().
Here is my code:

```
int main(){
char argv[200];
char** tokenList = NULL;

printf("shell>>");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", argv);
int len = 0;
char* line = strtok(argv, " ");
while (line != NULL) {
   printf("%s\n", line);
   printf("%lu\n", sizeof(tokenList) + (sizeof(char*) * (len+1)));
   tokenList = realloc(tokenList, sizeof(tokenList) + (sizeof(char*) * (len+1)));
   printf("%lu\n", sizeof(tokenList));
   char* p = malloc(sizeof(char) * (sizeof(line) + 1));
   p=line;
   tokenList[len] = p;
   len++;
   line = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
```

The three print statements are for my debugging purposes and I cannot figure out what is going on. When I run the shell and enter "a b c" my output is the following:

```
a
16
8
b
24
8
c
32
8
```

Why is the size of my array tokenList not getting updated by the realloc call?

Comment: A pointer is not an array! And that's not how C works anyway. There are no arrays with dynamic length in C. All types are statically declared. `realloc` just changes the size of a memory block (like `malloc` allocates it).

Comment: `sizeof()` only works during compilation, not in run-time. It determines the size of the object/variable given, not of anything it points to.

Comment: @Olaf: "There are no arrays with dynamic length in C." There are of course VLAs (variable length arrays), but the size of each VLA object is fixed at run time when it's created. This quibble is not related to what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I'm pretty sure you know that I know about VLAs:-). Yes, my comment is missleading. VLAs cannot change length once _defined_ (I should not have used _declared_). Dynamic arrays can change size and keep track of that change. If one needs that, for a 1D array a `struct` with flexible array member would be a good way. But there is no implicit length information.

Comment: @Olaf: Agreed. And as long as we're quibbling, "statically" is usually a reasonable term for something that's constant, but C's use of the word "static" to refer to a kind of storage allocation makes it inadvisable in this case. A named array object can be created with automatic or static storage duration; in either case its size is fixed when it's created. (I have no doubt that you know all this.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Just give me the bonus of being ESL. I just lack reasonable synonyms for "static":-) (Honestly, that's not just a lame excuse). Just to increase confusion: a VLA cannot be static ... :-)

Comment: @Olaf: Absolutely; your English is **much** better than my anything-other-than-English.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `sizeof` operator on a pointer. This yields the size in bytes **of the pointer**, not of the length of data pointed to. It's easy to imagine why,  since `tokenList` is just a variable that stores an address, you obtain the size of the variable, not of what the variable points to.

In C, arrays allocated on heap doesn't know their size, the developer must take care of knowing it and storing/updating it when necessary somewhere.

The only case in which you are allowed to use directly `sizeof` is when an array is declared with static or local storage (and not on heap). In this circumstance `sizeof` return the total length in bytes of the array, so that you can do `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` to obtain the element count.

Comment: Jack, that is not an "exception". It just calculates the size in bytes of the object/variable passed.